# Jenkins Build Number stamp

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

When I build a new version of my project with Jenkins, where does that new build number get placed in my project? Is there a way I can access it in my code?

Comment: Your question is a bit confused, version of project=verison of app (POM_VERSION for example) build number is used to jenkins to count jobs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not placed by default: the build number used by Jenkins is only visible/accesible during your job execution as the [environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

There are plugins helping you infer a more meaningful version number:

- [JENKINS Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin)
- [JENKINS Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)

But again, they only generate environment variables, they don't "place" that version number into your project.
That is something you have to do, as part of your build steps. See a concrete example in "[How to include Jenkins CI build number in Android APK name & app label](http://blog.jensdriller.com/how-to-include-jenkins-ci-build-number-in-android-apk-name/)"